# How to create a perspective view of a screen shot so that it appears as a photographed 3D object?

Tags: interface-design, representation

Ok so this is difficult to put in words but I want to know how designers present their Graphics Design work in screenshots something like this (source: [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com/shots/1177275-Side-Menu)):

[image]

Not about the iPhone but I'm talking about presenting the design as a photograph taken from side-view, I believe it is some sort of Photoshop thing but since I don't know what to call this pattern, I couldn't Google anything on this.

Similar examples are [this](http://dribbble.com/shots/1177291-Get-Started-Page), [this](http://dribbble.com/shots/1177355-Social-app) and many other on Dribbble.

Link to a brief tutorial on How-To creating such snap-shots would be great.

Comment: This would be a lot better to ask on Graphic Design, since you're asking how to do it and it's not a UX issue. If you were asking WHY they did it, then it'd be more of a UX question.

Comment: @Revolt: I'm unaware that dedicated Graphics Design site exists too, Moderator can move this question in that case.

Comment: @Kush - I answered it for you either way. But it should be moved, I'll flag it for a moderator.

Comment: @DA01 - He said it's NOT about the iPhone.

Comment: @Revolt then the question should be retitled if it's strictly asking how the distort/perspective tool works in PhotoShop

Comment: @DA01 or you could just read it and see what he's asking. He shows 2 other examples of what he wants, and those don't have a phone.

Comment: @DA01: As I said I didn't knew what to call this pattern (my bad), if it was just a matter of playing around Perspective tool, I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place rather than having the title mentioning "Perpective/Distort tool".

Comment: I'll update the title to accomodate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a UX question, but assuming it's going to be moved to Graphic Design, I'll answer it so that my answer is moved with it.

You can accomplish this in Photoshop CS4 (not sure about others), by selecting your layer, then going to edit > transform > perspective, and moving the boxes around until you get what you want.

You can see in the bottom right a layer that I used it on.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a web service that lets you create realistic looking product shots of mobile devices.

http://placeit.breezi.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin:
https://dribbble.com/blazrobar/projects/119709-Perspective-Actions

Or search in Google "perspective mockups" and will find resources.

Comment: Hi Miguel, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!